# What does it mean when some players show as level zero?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Every once in a while of playing online, I notice some people are in the game but they are shown as level zero.  They don't have a templar profile that I may view, I can only mute their chat but can't block them (or any other action).  It can't just be a first time player, everyone (AFAIK) starts at level one.

At first I thought they were just people who have just played through the tutorial missions and are in the post-tutorial game but some of them I've encountered have non-default ability sets.  I've even found one level zero player using the **Count** with *all* the level three customizations (such as the headbutt stun).  I'm finding more and more often now that people with "lag problems" (read: cheating) are people showing up as level 0 more than any other.

So who are these people exactly?  Why don't they have any information on them?

Comment: A decent indicator as to whether or not they're cheating: Check their gamercard. Nine times out of ten, they'll have very low gamerscore, and every game in their Games Played list will have -- in place of gamerscore.

Comment: Yeah that too.  It's annoying when you get into a game where there's someone "ghosting" around the map basically getting free stuns and kills.  Or those that will stand in one corner of the map the whole time and somehow manage to get kills on someone on the opposite end.  Or those that causes _all_ civilians to stop moving around.  I'm running into these games too often at times.

Comment: There IS a kill streak reward that lets you kill people from anywhere on the map. The Animus Hack, I think it's called. But you have to have a 7 or 9 kill streak to get it.

Comment: I know that, but it isn't even the animus hacks that they kill you with.  Their bodies will magically appear next to you, get the kill, then disappear.

Comment: I suppose this is on PC version. I never has this problem on PS3 where cheating is much more limited (which is one of the main reasons why I started to only play online on console)

Comment: @LudoMC: I am playing on the PC version but I'm not sure if the level zero players thing is unique to this version.  I figured this is something that appears on the console versions as well (never mind about the cheaters aspect).

Comment: I'll double-check next time but so far (I'm level 40) I've never seen any 0 level players. I'm on PS3.

Comment: i experienced the same thing. "level zero" blank profiles of players who were obviously lvl 50 ... why cheat when the rest of us are trying to level up? the Prestige points? Like the rest of us don't want to be level 50 with all the customization options, too. super frustrating cuz the team modes put the level zeros together, thinking that they are lowbies. when i get in a game with cheaters, i begin the game, let them think they are gonna get some points, and then quit. if they are gonna cheat, they're not gonna exploit my gaming experience to do it.

Comment: Bah, the cheating is getting worse and worse now... :(  Some are not even trying to be discreet doing the level zero stuff anymore, I saw a level 30ish player with all level 3 customizations including secondary katar (prestige 5 item) and literally flying around the map... I wonder if it was ever this bad in ACB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with either Ubisoft bugging up (like always), or there is a patch which needs to be installed, but they are not cheating.

Maybe it has something to do with NAT classification.

Comment: A lot of the level zero players are not cheating, I know that.  It's just the sometimes it is a little too convenient that the cheaters just happen to be showing as level zero. The possible cheaters I'm seeing nowadays are of varying levels (with those with profiles having horrible stats, coincidence?).

Comment: Ah, you might be on to something about players needing patches, [this guy](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/657291-Old-PC-patch-download) is showing as level zero to others and everyone shows as level zero to him.  Apparently he hasn't patched his game yet... I would have thought that you'd need to have the latest version of the game to be able to play with everyone else...

Comment: So it turned out that not _everyone_ had kept up with the latest patch. So if you were behind back at the time, you would appear to those up to date as level 0. I don't know if this is still the case now that we're at patch 1.03 but it was certainly the case back then. It's really stupid that they even let mismatching versions play together in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

*Probably* doesn't mean that they're cheating. Well, at least, not in the sense of animus-level hacks. Since there's really too many of those Level 0 guys in every match, and they hardly ever rank in the top 3 either.

What I would think is that they somehow unlocked more abilities than they're allowed to have, which is kinda fine, since getting those abilities =/= playing better. Also makes me feel less guilty for using all the unlocked abilities against someone who's still using the default firecrackers and knives.